# "device.interfaces" is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a usb driver to change my keyboard lighting using the libusb library in typescript, but when I want to get the interface number says that my function as possibly undefined. I am writing the code in windows, but I written the exact same code from a tutorial, but the os was linux.

here is the code:

```
import * as usb from 'usb';

const VID = 0X0C45;
const PID = 0x672E;
const IN = 1;

const main = async () => {

    const device = usb.findByIds(VID, PID);

    console.log(device);

    device?.open();

const deviceInterface = device?.interfaces[IN]; <-problem is here
    
    console.log(deviceInterface);
}

main();
```

What should i do?

Apparently if I insert a "?" resolves the problem, but the compiler shows an error , ": expected"

Comment: "Apparently if I insert a "?" resolves the problem" the correct syntax is `x.foo?.bar?.[0]` you need the extra dot even though it's an array index to make it syntactically distinct from a ternary https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=28&pln=9&pc=13#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYD8AXDvgcgEZxRnIgCuAttdANoC6lAvrv1wJ0IAM5hkAD3IYsAXhyDhY9ABsIAOlXoA5gApJGoumIba9DRwAMXAJQBuXEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you add another `?` and you get the error `: expected` TypeScript is thinking you are trying to write a ternary statement there.  Like

```ts
device?.interfaces ? [IN] : 'foo'
```

Obviously you don't want that, you want to do another null check there.

There are a few ways to fix this.  One way is to just do your own null check with an if statement like this

```ts
const deviceInterface = device?.interfaces;
if(deviceInterface){
    const myInterface = deviceInterface[IN]
    console.log(myInterface);
}
```

Here's [the full code on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=6&pln=12&pc=5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wK6oEZwGZQQhwDkW2JA3ALABQdAxhAHarwBqAkgCJwC8cAAwANQQGEALAFYatJq3gAFHvyEAPAGwB2AEwBRWfLZxOAOVUBGWYxbGQyYM1VoAnswZwAFAEp+APjgAbzo4ULgjeAATAFMAN2AGaNVyADo8R0iAIRdOSNRPLm4AGjhlbm9ZMPDbCAAbaJTaiABzTxj4xIqQsPaE6IB+FIgwaOYfa1oqiLhexM5mGGioPGRE1VmBlMdF5dXo1Eqw4Dw2uL75nZXO4MmqsOmQHIWlq6SBDYuXvYBtMwBdbp3aqsOoNJqtR6fXadQ6hAC+dAR9Fo9kc4yAA)

The other, as pointed out in the comments by @JaredSmith, is to use the correct null check syntax for arrays, which is:

```ts
device?.interfaces?.[IN]
```

Here's [the full code on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wK6oEZwGZQQhwDkW2JA3ALABQdAxhAHarwBqAkgCJwC8cAAwANQQGEALAFYatJq3gAFHvyEAPAGwB2AEwBRWfLZxOAOVUBGWYxbGQyYM1VoAnswZwAFAEp+APjgAbzo4ULgjeAATAFMAN2AGaNVyADo8R0iAIRdOSNRPLm4AGjhlbm9ZMPDbCAAbaJTaiABzTxj4xIqQsPaE6IB+FIgwaOYfa1oqiLhexM5mGGioPGRE1VmBlMdF5dXo1EGAbTMAXUqwozqGptaN+Z2VztkAXzo6e0dxoA)

Comment: You can still use the null accessor for an array index it just needs a dot `x.foo?.bar?.[0]`. This is (as you correct point out) to make it syntactically distinct from a ternary https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=28&pln=9&pc=13#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYD8AXDvgcgEZxRnIgCuAttdANoC6lAvrv1wJ0IAM5hkAD3IYsAXhyDhY9ABsIAOlXoA5gApJGoumIba9DRwAMXAJQBuXEA

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I knew it could be done but I forgot the syntax. I will update my answer to include this as well